# asp.net mvc chrome gets stuck on data breach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application with a user log-in. I keep session information with `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` when logged in. Still, the following notification comes on chrome
that has detected the password you just used was exposed as a result of a data breach. To ensure your account's security, we recommend you change your password now and check your saved password.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Change your password. This is not a coding issue

Comment: go through this link : https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23534509?hl=en&msgid=23534509